# Como fazer comparação de números em lista de vetor?

Tags: java, array, lista, arraylist

Eu tenho uma lista de vetor inteiro no java (ArrayList ListVet).

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> ListVet;
```

E eu preciso fazer uma comparação entre dois números dessa mesma lista de vetor. Então, eu fiz assim:

```
for (int i=0; i<ListVet.size();i++)

{

      if (ListVet[i] > ListVet[i+1])

      {

      }             

}
```

No entanto, ocorreu esse erro:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to      ArrayList

Por que ocasionou este erro? Obrigado.

Comment: Simples: um objeto do tipo `ArrayList` não é um vetor, então não aceita o operador de índice `[idx]`. Creio que você deseja usar o método `get(idx)` nesse caso em específico. Aproveitando, seu código tem um bug de tempo de execução: o último índice que se pode acessar é `list.size() - 1`, e com a variável `i` você chega exatamente nesse valor, porém você também usa `i+1` que ultrapassa os limites e, portanto, estoura exceção

Answer (score 3):

ArrayList é um objeto, e como em Java não tem como sobrescrever operadores como `[]` para acessar a posição da lista, você tem que usar métodos, ou seja, `ListVet.get(i) > ListVet.get(i+1)`

Se você criar um array propriamente dito, que tem tamanho estático, como `Integer[] ListVet`, aí sim você irá acessar com `ListVet[i]`.

Comment: E se eu quisesse fazer com que o valor da lista de vetor anterior recebesse o valor da lista de vetor posterior? Tipo: ListVet[i] = ListVet[i+1]. No vetor seria assim, mas na lista de vetor, não funciona assim.

Comment: Você teria que usar outro método, ListVet.set(i, ListVet.get(i+1))

Comment: O primeiro é o valor da lista, e o segundo é o valor que vai substituir o "i", correto?

Comment: O primeiro argumento corresponde a posição da lista, e o segundo ao valor que você irá inserir.

Comment: Obrigado. :) :)

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida: Como eu converto um ArrayList Inteiro para String, e vice-versa? Obrigado.

Comment: Abra uma nova pergunta e explique melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: @GabrielAugusto Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, você pode aceitá-la, veja como fazer [lendo o FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052). Aliás, sugiro que considere fazer o mesmo (aceitar uma resposta, caso ela tenha resolvido o seu problema) em todas as suas perguntas anteriores, pois isso é útil para futuros visitantes que tenham a mesma dúvida, já que isso indica que aquilo de fato solucionou o problema. Claro que vc não é obrigado a aceitar nenhuma resposta, mas se ela foi útil e resolveu o seu problema, é importante fazê-lo pelos motivos citados no link do FAQ que citei

Comment: @GabrielAugusto E conforme já foi sugerido, se você tiver outras dúvidas, não hesite em [abrir uma nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). O site funciona com perguntas bem focadas e específicas, e se tiver dúvidas sobre outras coisas (mesmo que sejam relacionadas), o ideal é abrir novas perguntas, uma para cada dúvida específica - não se esquecendo de pesquisar antes se a pergunta já existe no site, claro - veja mais detalhes na página **[ask]** e no [Manual de como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/112052)